# Troubleshooting Excel- compare cell to range them copy text in next column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets. One has a column of text. The other has a column of text and an adjacent column with a number.

I want to compare each cell to the range on another sheet. If the text on sheet B is found I want to pull the number next to the column in sheet A and put it next to column next to the string on sheet B.

This seems to work for the first cell, but when I copy/paste it returns 0.

=IF(COUNTIF(D2,'ClientKW Input'!$B$1:$B$337),'ClientKW Input'!$A$1:$A$337,0)

For column D2 it returns the correct number but not for d3 and other cells?!?

Comment: Hi Colin, I think you will want to use the [VLOOKUP function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function) to do your comparison and fetch.You may also find you wish to wrap a [IFERROR function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-iferror-function) around the VLOOKUP for cases where the text isn't found. I hope that helps

Comment: How do I write the fetch?

When it identifies the cell with matching text I want to take the data in next column and copy it to put next to the column it's comparing.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `INDEX MATCH` to achieve this. Something like the following:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B, MATCH(Sheet2!A1, Sheet1!A:A, 0))
```

In the above example, the data you are pulling is in Sheet 1 col B, the value you are using to search is Sheet 2 col A, matching up with Sheet 1 col A. You might have to change this for you specific needs.

Comment: OK, so if things match, how do I then select the contents of the cell next to the matched data and put in the cell next to the source (sheet 1)?

Thx

Comment: I want to say "if cell b2 matches any of sheet2 cells b1:999 then copy the matching cell in the sheet 2 B range and paste it into cell c2"

Then repeat for each.   I'm stuck with how do I say "when you match it on sheet2, take the data in next cell on sheet 2 and paste next to this source data"

Comment: So you're looking for a VBA option? What you're describing "if something matches take the next cells data" is completely achievable with the above formula. If you're looking to copy and paste then you will have to write a macro, which means reading how https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-cells-vba-macros/ for example and posting a new question as and when you get stuck.

Comment: OK thanks Tim!  

I suspect the issue will be how to reference the location of what needs pasted  as being the cell next to the one found in the comparison